# Elementary OS is overheating my laptop. why? How to fix it?

Tags: battery

I just finished installing Elementary OS and I realized that my laptop is overheating. Before I installed EOS I used Ubuntu 11.04 and everything was fine. Also the time to charge the battery is now very long. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Latest version of eOS is full of bug so it's better not to install it before stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing TLP, an advanced power management tool using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

More information on TLP you can find at: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html

Also, install cpufrequtils using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally is about the GPU (Graphic Card). I had same issue and I have installed external GPU (Nvidia) driver. Then set laptop performance to normal with

> tuned-adm

. The problem is solved